# POSIX Shell: `exec` with changed arg0

Tags: shell, posix, exec

I want to `exec` a program and control it's arguments including arg0 and environment. Using C I could go for `execve`. Can I do this in POSIX shell?

Comment: Depending on the situation, you could make a symlink with the desired arg0 and exec that instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to POSIX documentation of [Special Builtin Utilities](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#exec), the syntax for exec is

```
exec [command [argument...]]
```

Environment of the calling shell **should** be propagated to *command* so setting it prior to exec-ing like `foo=bar exec cmd` should just work. However, you might want to consider the *Rationale* paragraph.

> Most historical implementations were not conformant in that: foo=bar
> exec cmd did not pass foo to cmd.

There is also no built-in way to fiddle argv[0].
a possible workaround could consist in symlinking *some_name* to *command* prior to `exec some_name` (full credit to [muru](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/70524/muru))

Note that [*bash*](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sh) [*zsh*](https://linux.die.net/man/1/zshbuiltins) and [*ksh*](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E36870/ksh-1.html) do support an extended implementation of the exec command :

```
exec [-cl] [-a name] [command [arguments]]
```

which, thanks, to the -a option enables *name* to stand as `argv[0]`

> with -a argv0 set the argv[0] string of the command executed

However, neither *csh* nor *dash* nor *fish* support that.

Comment: A symlink won't always do the trick, because the path component may often be different from the intended argv[0], although the basename can be the same.